Flutter WebView JavaScript <input type="file"> not triggering file picker dialog
I'm trying to implement file selection within a Flutter WebView using JavaScript. My goal is to let users select images through an <input type="file"> element. Here's the JavaScript code snippet I'm using inside my HTML:
<input
  ref="imageInput"
  title="Image"
  v-if="!isMute"
  type="file"
  data-type="image"
  accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/bmp,.jpg,.image,.webp"
  @change="sendUploadMessage"
  :style="{ cursor: 'pointer' }"
/>

However, when I tap on the <input type="file"> element in the WebView, nothing happens – the file picker dialog doesn’t appear.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Enabled JavaScript in the WebView with the following Flutter code:
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'your_url',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)


Tested on both iOS and Android, but no file dialog appears.

Additional Information:

Flutter version: 3.22.0
WebView package: webview_flutter (tried with the latest version)
Devices: Tested on both Android and iOS

Is there a specific workaround or configuration needed to allow <input type="file"> in a Flutter WebView? Or do I need to use a platform channel to handle file selection outside of the WebView?
Thank you for any help or insights!
